# Dice game with an opponent

Tags: combinatorics, dice

I and my opponent play a game of dices. I win if my opponent didn't throw a dice in our game with a higher number than my highest number.

Example :
I have 2 dices, he's got 3 . 
Our throws : (1,4,2,4,3) , I threw 1,4 he 2,3,4. I won in this case because he didn't get any higher number than my 4. (he should've gotten a 5 or 6) The dices are also distinguishable.

**Give the number of possible combinations in which I can win if:**

1) I have 2 dices, he's got 1.

2) I have 3 dices and my opponent 2.

My incomplete solution:(let $i$ be my throws and $o$ for opponent)

1) (i1, i2, o1) here are possible $6^3$ total combinations .

$wins=6^3 - |o1>max(i1,i2)|$ (but I don't know how to count it)

2) no idea

Thank you.

Comment: Are you expected to give the *number* of possible combinations, or list out all the combinations?  There are quite a few of them for part (2).

Comment: @BrianTung count all possible combinations in which I turn out as a winner.

Comment: Are the dice distinguishable?  In other words, in (1), if you roll a 4 and a 5, is that different from rolling a 5 and a 4?

Comment: These numbers are small enough that I would just start listing the possibilities out.  You may begin to see some regularities that will permit you to count them more efficiently.  Since the dice are not distinguishable, there are not, in fact, $6^3 = 216$ combinations of three dice.  (For example, 1/2/3 is not different from 3/2/1.)  This complicates the count quite a bit.

Comment: @BrianTung the answer for a) is 161 and b) 5593

Comment: @BrianTung sorry for misleading you , they are distiguinshable

Comment: You’re comparing the maximum of your die rolls to the minimum of your opponent’s, so you can use [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) to do this calculation.

Comment: To the OP:  English is a funny language.  "Dice" is the plural form of "die," so it sounds wrong (to native speakers) to say "dices."  But don't look for any consistency in the "die/dice" rule:  It also sounds wrong to say, for example, that Donald Trump's rhetoric is full of lice....

Comment: @BarryCipra thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have $\max(Z_1, Z_2, Z_3, ..., Z_n) = m$ for dice $Z_i$ and max outcome $m$, then you have $M_{m,n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (m-1)^{n-k}$ ways to get that outcome.

You choose $k$ of the dice to equal $m$, and then the remaining $n-k$ dice can take on one of $m-1$ remaining values each. This simplifies to $M_{m,n} = m^n - (m-1)^n$

So for each max we can achieve, $m_1$, we wish to compute the number of ways we can achieve that max, multiplied by the number of ways the opponent achieves a max $m_2 \leq m_1$.

Let $m_1, a$ be our max and number of dice, and let $m_2, b$ be the opponent's max and number of dice. Let $F(a, b)$ be the number of ways we can win given $a, b$ dice.

$$F(a, b) = \sum_{m_1=1}^{6} \sum_{m_2=1}^{m_1} (m_1^{a} - (m_1-1)^{a})(m_2^{b} - (m_2-1)^{b})$$

This can be simplified to a closed-form expression:

$$F(a, b) = 1 - 2^{b} + 2^{a + b} - 2^{a} 3^{b} + 3^{a + b} - 3^{a} 4^{b} + 4^{a + b} - 4^{a} 5^{b} + 5^{a + b} - 5^{a} 6^{b} + 6^{a + b}$$

See that $F(2, 1) = 161$ and $F(3, 2) = 5593$.

Answer (score 0):

$(1).~161$
 
$(2).~1071$
 
combination are possible to win the game.